# Finding an orthonormal basis for the row space of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, orthonormal

> Find an orthonormal basis for the row space of $$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & -3 \\ -5 & 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix} $$

---

Let $v_1 = (2\  -1 \  -3)$ and $v_2 = (-5 \ \ \ 5 \ \ \ 3)$. Using [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), I found an orthonormal basis $$e_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{14}} (2\  -1 \  -3), \qquad e_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (-1 \ \ \ 2 \ \ \ 0)$$ So, an orthonormal basis for the row space of $A =\{ e_1,e_2\}$. Is the solution correct?

Comment: Did you try checking if the two vectors you obtained are orthogonal (i.e. their dot product is $0$)? You should also probably show us the steps in your working, so we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: Even more importantly, have you checked that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are actually elements of the row space?

Answer (score 1):

Verify your Gram-Schmidt process again.

Note that we have $V_1=X_1$ and  $V_2 = X_2-\frac {X_2.V_1}{V_1.V_1}V_1$

My calculations did not match with yours.